# Regex to match a hyphen in a string 0 or 1 times

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to build a regex that will check to see if a string has a hyphen 0 or 1 times.

So it would return the following strings as ok.

```
1-5
1,3-5
1,3
```

The following would be wrong.

```
1-3-5
```

I have tried the following, but it is fine with 1-3-5:

```
([^-]?-){0,1}[^-]
```

Comment: Can't you do it the other way around: create a regex that matches if a string contains two hyphens? Also, is this really all you want to do? Wouldn't it make sense to fully parse the string (digits, commas, everything)?

Comment: I would likely split on `,` and then use a regex/count on each component - this is off the assumption that `1-2,4-5` is also valid, even if not shown so. The regular expression to match "more than 1 dash", when divided into components, is as simple as `-.*?-` (if this matches there is more than one dash); however, if the values also need to be extracted, considered starting to from an accepting-of-input vs a rejecting-of-dash approach.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This works:

```
^[^-]*-?[^-]*$
^^    ^ ^    ^
||    | |    |
||    | |    |-- Match the end of string
||    | |------- Match zero or more non-hyphen characters
||    |--------- Match zero or one hyphens
||-------------- Match zero or more non-hyphen characters
|--------------- Match the beginning of string
```

In this case, you need to specify matching the beginning (`^`) and end (`$`) of the input strings, so that you don't get multiple matches for a string like `1-3-5`.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps something simpler:

```
var hyphens = input.Count(cc => cc == '-');
```

Your regular expression works because it found the first instance of a hyphen, which meets your criteria. You could use the following regular expression, but it would not be ideal:

```
^[^-]*-?[^-]*$
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have your strings in a collection, you could do this in one line of LINQ. It'll return a list of strings that have less than two hyphens in them.

```
var okStrings = allStrings.Where(s => s.Count(h => h == '-') < 2).ToList();
```

Judging by the way you've formatted the list of strings I assume you can't split on the comma because it's not a consistent delimiter. If you can then you can just using the `String.Split` method to get each string and replace the `allStrings` variable above with that array.

Answer (score 0):

You could approach it this way:

```
string StringToSearch = "1-3-5";
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches("-", StringToSearch);
if(matches.Count == 0 || matches.Count == 1)
{
  //...
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I just tested your expression and it appears to give the result you want. It break 1-3-5 into {1-3} and {-5}

http://regexpal.com/